# Can you help resolve this error? (g++ prototype does not match any in class)

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Here's the compiler output:

```
[brian@brian-arch-laptop Lab1]$ g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 objectIO.cpp main.cpp -o main
objectIO.cpp:33:14: error: prototype for ‘std::vector<Type> objectIO<Type>::loadObjects(Type, std::string, unsigned int, unsigned int)’ does not match any in class ‘objectIO<Type>’
 vector<Type> objectIO<Type>::loadObjects(Type dummyObject,
              ^
objectIO.h:14:23: error: candidate is: static std::vector<Type> objectIO<Type>::loadObjects(std::string, unsigned int, unsigned int)
   static vector<Type> loadObjects(Type dummyObject, string fileName, unsigned numObjects,unsigned numLinesPerObject);
                   ^
```

from my research, I've discovered that this error typically happens when one has declared a function, but when they define it, it has a different number of arguments or arguments of different types. I've also found that this error normally happens when one declares a function using "const" but then fails to use "const" when defining the function.

Neither of those cases match my situation. I have matching aruments, and I'm not making my functions constant. Here are the lines in question from my source:

From my source (.cpp) file:

```
template <class Type>
vector<Type> objectIO<Type>::loadObjects(Type dummyObject,
                     string filename,
                     unsigned numObjects,
                     unsigned numLinesPerObject){/*functionality here*/}
```

From my header (.h) file:

```
template <class Type>
class objectIO{
 public:
  static vector<Type> loadObjects(Type dummyObject, string fileName,
                  unsigned numObjects,
                  unsigned numLinesPerObject);

}
```

Comment: it's not a g++ error, it's a programmer error...

Comment: I don't know how this doesn't work, but try to put the function definition in the header file. Because your code worked for me (http://ideone.com/IaKARx)

Comment: I got too this error multiple times.

According to the documentation, if a member function is using the template feature, than it's definition must be placed in the header file, and not in the source file.

Comment: According to the compiler, the declaration in the header file is missing the first parameter (that has type `Type`).  `candidate is: static std::vector<Type> objectIO<Type>::loadObjects(std::string, unsigned int, unsigned int)`

Answer (score 1):

All definition of a template class shall be placed in one header file.

Comment: This is a good practice and helps prevent "undefined reference" errors later, but isn't actually a requirement.

Comment: If you are not going to explicitly instantiate a template function then it is a requirement.

Comment: Anything that makes the function definition available before its instantiation will work.  Explicit instantiation is ok.  Putting in the same header file is ok.  Putting in another header file is ok.  Not actually calling the function is ok.  Getting lucky because the file with the definition implicitly instantiated it with all the same types is ok.  Your suggestion fixes a linker error, but this question has a compile error.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I think you arer right. I did not think that his original code contains a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys! Moving it all to the header file worked. I just wish I knew how to keep them separate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a semicolon after the class's closing brace:

```
template <class Type>
class objectIO{
 public:
  static vector<Type> loadObjects(Type dummyObject, string fileName,
                  unsigned numObjects,
                  unsigned numLinesPerObject);

} /* <-- RIGHT HERE */
```

That usually messes up whatever comes next in the source code, sometimes with a really mistaken error message.

Comment: The semicolon was in my source code, it just didn't copy over. Moving all of my code to the header file fixed my problem.